# whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1) , errorCode='AXONIQ-5001

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon-framework

```
 I have two service service1 and service2 .In service2 QueryHandler is there and if i will run only service2 QueryHandler working but if I am calling this QueryHandler in service1 then not working and both service are running in axon server but while calling service2 queryhandler in service1 I am getting below error.
```

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.axonframework.queryhandling.QueryExecutionException:
Caused by: AxonServerRemoteQueryHandlingException{message=An exception was thrown by the remote message handling component:
Caused by only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1) , errorCode='AXONIQ-5001', location='10712@INN1FJ2WZ2'}
at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.ErrorCode.lambda$static$15(ErrorCode.java:107)

## service1

```
 @Autowired
private QueryGateway queryGateway;
TXodsFetchDocumentDetails fetchDocumentDetails = TXodsFetchDocumentDetails.builder()
                                                            .transactionReference(res.getEventHeader().getTransactionTrackingDetails().getStepDetails().getTxTransactionDetails().getTransactionReference())
                                                            .stepNumber(res.getEventHeader().getTransactionTrackingDetails().getStepDetails().getStepNumber())
                                                            .build();

        
            TXOdsDocumentObjectList tXOdsDocumentObjectList1=queryGateway
                    .query(fetchDocumentDetails, TXOdsDocumentObjectList.class).join();//here throwing exception
```

## service2

```
@QueryHandler
    public TXOdsDocumentObjectList handle(TXodsFetchDocumentDetails fetchDocumentDetails) {
        log.info("Retrieve all document details request ", fetchDocumentDetails.getTransactionReference(),fetchDocumentDetails.getStepNumber());
        List<TXOdsDocumentObject> documentObjectList = repository
                .findByEventHeader_TransactionTrackingDetails_StepDetails_TxTransactionDetails_TransactionReferenceAndEventHeader_TransactionTrackingDetails_StepDetails_StepNumber(
                        fetchDocumentDetails.getTransactionReference(), fetchDocumentDetails.getStepNumber());
        return TXOdsDocumentObjectList.builder().documentObjectList(documentObjectList).build();
    }
```

I am new to the AXON framework please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the serializer configuration in application.properties, make sure the query command sending component is using the same XStream(XML)/Jackson(Json) serializer as the receiving (QueryHandler) component, like below:

```
axon.serializer.messages=jackson
```

I fixed such a mistake recently by doing so, hope it can give you some clue